# How does Cassandra handle lightweight transactions in split-brain mode?

Tags: cassandra, consistency

I had thought that updating with `IF` and using an appropriate write consistency level would ensure consistency even in the event of a network partition (receiving and exception if it isn't possible), but I'm told that isn't so.

If two lightweight transactions occur on the same row while Cassandra is in split-brain mode, how are they resolved once the network partition disappears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If two lightweight transactions occur on the same row while Cassandra is in split-brain mode, how are they resolved once the network partition disappears?

Every cell value has a timestamp. Cassandra configuration requieres ntp configuration on every server. So if your consistency level would allow to acknowledge operations in both split parts, then cell timestamps would be compared and newer value should win.

Comment: So there's no way to use a `QUORUM` or `ALL` write consistency level to effectively say, "If you can't guarantee that my transaction will be consistent, consider that an error"? I thought that was the point of tunable consistency. If clients in two partitions can say `UPDATE t set a=X IF a=Y` for two different values of X and the same Y, lightweight transactions have no safety at all, do they?

Comment: What I described was for scenario if two queries would be acknowledge in split-brain. But if you'd have e.g. `ALL`, and part of data replicas would be in one split part, and part in second one, then the requiered number of acks can not be achieved, so query will be rejected with some error that only X from Y nodes replied. Effectively you'd have only one accepted lightweight transaction instead of two, so no conflict would need to be resolved later.